# Table cell creation warning/error about IBlockElement

Tags: itext

Just starting to try and use iText (latest version) and following some online examples. However, this bit of code in Visual Studio 2019, VB:

```
Dim cell1 = New Cell    
cell1.Add("Name")
```

gives me an intellisense warning/error in the editor saying:

> Runtime errors might occur when converting 'String' to 'IBlockElement'.

Why doesn't the cell.ADD argument accept strings as per online code examples please?
(I am also not well versed in using `Interfaces` either!)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't the cell.ADD argument accept strings as per online code examples please?

Apparently the online code examples you saw were created at the time of the early 7.0.x versions. But the whole table API has been overhauled in 7.1.0 including some breaking changes.

Thus, in the current version create an `IBlockElement` (e.g. a `Paragraph`) containing your text and add that block element to your table cell.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I wondered if there was something like that going on!
But when you say 'breaking changes' do you mean changes that have broken things?  Or that they are very recent - as in 'breaking news' ?

Do you know of any updated documentation?

However, as I'm sure you know, the 'IBlockElement' is an interface  - which I'm not really up on - but what I think I know is that it can't be instantiated?
So how do I create an object of some type that uses that interface?
Sorry if this might be a bit of a numpty question!!

Comment: As I'm under pressure with this task, I've installed itext v7.0.8 and all now works as per docs!!
Thanks for your help mkl !!

Comment: Great that the answer helped. You may want to mark it as "accepted answer" by clicking the tick at its upper left side, right underneath the voting arrows.

Comment: @JimButler Anyways, though, you should try and learn about interfaces. They are quite central to the APIs of many libraries.

Comment: @Jim any special reason why you un-accepted the answer?